# Changing shape color of a Visio Title block object

Tags: c#, interop, visio

I am trying to change the color of a "Title Block small" shape, which I initially thought was pretty easy.
I must be barking up the wrong tree, because I can't seem to make it work.
I am using the below code, to set the 18 individual cells to the desired color, but no dice.

`foreach(Shape s in TitleShape.Shapes) { s.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject, (short)VisRowIndices.visRowFill, (short)VisCellIndices.visFillBkgnd).FormulaForceU = "RGB(255,255,255)"; }`

I have also tried TitleShape.get_CellsSRC(bla bla bla).FormulaForceU directly, but nothing happens.

Can I get a hint, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,0))"
```

works in VBA

Comment: Thank you, changing to foreground instead of background did it.